How to Force a Specific Value to Appear at the Top in SQL Sorting?
I'm working on sorting a list of names in ascending order while ensuring that a specific value always appears at the top of the list. I have the following SQL query:
SELECT 
    province_name
FROM
    province_names
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN province_name = 'Ontario' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
    province_name;

This query successfully places 'Ontario' at the top, followed by the other province names sorted in ascending order. However, I would like to understand the underlying logic and mechanisms that make this method work. Additionally, I'm interested in learning about alternative approaches to achieve this result.
Example Context
Consider a table province_names with the following data:



province_name




Alberta


Quebec


Ontario


Manitoba


British Columbia



Desired output:



province_name




Ontario


Alberta


British Columbia


Manitoba


Quebec



Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

The expression CASE WHEN province_name = 'Ontario' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END yields 0 in the case of Ontario in province_name, 1 otherwise. You ask to have the result ordered on that, and in the case of identical values on that column, on province_name as the secondary order.

Why does this work?
The answer is relatively simple. Your ORDER BY clause can be thought of as ORDER BY condition1, condition2 where condition1 takes precedence over condition2.
In your case condition1 is (CASE WHEN province_name = 'Ontario' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), that means this expression evaluates to 0 for Ontario and 1 for all other provinces. You can think of it as if there was a column for the evaluated expression that the database sorts by:



province_name
evaluated_expression




Alberta
1


Quebec
1


Ontario
0


Manitoba
1


British Columbia
1



Now since the default sort order is ascending and we want to order by this imaginary evaluated_expression column Ontario will be on top since it is the smallest value and all other values will come after it.
Since all other rows in the table have the same value, they have the same order as far as the first condition is concerned. Now though,  the second condition will be evaluated which is the province_name. This will be sorted alphabetically in ascending order based on your database collation.
Other methods
There are many other methods. One that I can think of at the minute is the following:
SELECT province_name
FROM (
    SELECT 1, province_name 
    FROM province_names WHERE province_name = 'Ontario'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, province_name 
    FROM province_names 
    WHERE province_name <> 'Ontario'
    ORDER BY 1, province_name) subquery;

Here the idea is to have a subquery which

queries the record that is supposed to be on top and add a column with the constant value 1
uses UNION ALL to append to the result set
queries all the other records which are not supposed to be on top and adds a column with the constant value 2 and then it orders by 1 and then province_name giving you this result:




province_name





Ontario
1


Alberta
2


British Columbia
2


Manitoba
2


Quebec
2



Now you have the order you want but unfortunately also this column that you don't need. To get rid of that we need the main query which just selects the first column of above table and you get your desired result.
This approach however doesn't exactly make the query easier. Also as correctly pointed out in the comments this approach works (I've tested it with MySQL 8.0 and Postgres 15) but it's not guranteed to work since the ORDER BY in the subquery doesn't necessarily affect the main query. For SQL Server you might get an error (See this SO thread). So, that means, don't use this, use the first approach.
Another way to go about it is of course to store an order in the database at all times in a separate column province_order. This would allow you to define your custom order of provinces, but of course you'll pay the price of additional storage required.

ORDER BY in a subquery doesn't guarantee anything.
